# Trying to save a .csv with two specific ranges to a specific file location

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I'm trying to save four sets of cells, B2:B5, D2:D5, F2:F5, and C9:C62 to one .csv file, which should save to a specified location. This is what I have now, but it doesn't save correctly, and I am not able to tell if the rest of it works. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Dim myCSVFileName As String
    Dim myWB As Workbook
    Dim tempWB As Workbook
    Dim rngToSave As Range

    
    Set myWB = ActiveWorkbook ' or ThisWorkbook


    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error GoTo err

    myCSVFileName = "C:\Users\User Name\Desktop\Final Test Improvement" & "Product Name" & "_" & Range("B3").Value & "_" & ".csv"

    Set tempWB = Application.Workbooks.Add(1)
    With tempWB
        Set rngToSave = myWB.Worksheets("SheetOne").Range("A2:F5")
        rngToSave.Copy
        .Sheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Set rngToSave = myWB.Worksheets("SheetOne").Range("C9:C62")
        rngToSave.Copy
        .Sheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .SaveAs Filename:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With

err:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: And what is not working as intended?

Answer (score 0):

The `Range("A2:F5")` values are being overwritten because they span 4 rows and the `Range("C9:C62")` values are being pasted to `A2`.

There is no need for the error handler or copy and paste.

```
Private Sub CommandButton3_Click()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Dim myCSVFileName As String

    myCSVFileName = "C:\Users\User Name\Desktop\Final Test Improvement" & "Product Name" & "_" & Range("B3").Value & "_" & ".csv"
    
    Dim Target1 As Range, Target2 As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetOne")
        Set Target1 = .Range("A2:F5")
        Set Target2 = .Range("C9:C62")
    End With
    
    With Workbooks.Add(1)
        With .Sheets(1).Range("A1")
            .Resize(Target1.Rows.Count, Target1.Columns.Count).Value = Target1.Value
            .Offset(Target1.Rows.Count).Resize(Target2.Rows.Count, Target2.Columns.Count).Value = Target2.Value
        End With
        
        .SaveAs Filename:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```